# Delete Record in Java using SQL

Tags: java, mysql

Update: I tried the below suggestions, however it is still not working. When trying employeeid=1, it does say successful, however went going into mysql command line, it still shows the record there.

I tried looking at different posts and my insert works but for some reason i am unable to the delete function to work.

I am trying to delete a record but keep getting an error. Running mysql & netbeans. Please help, thank you.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try {

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `abcinc`.`employees`"
                + "(`EmployeeID`,`First_Name`,`Last_Name`,`Birthday`,`Dept_Name`)VALUES("
                + "'" + jTextField1.getText() + "'," 
                + "'" + jTextField2.getText() + "'," 
                + "'" + jTextField3.getText() + "'," 
                + "'" + jTextField4.getText() + "',"
                + "'" + jTextField5.getText() + "');");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful Update!!!", "Database Messages",
                      JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, error.getMessage(), "Database Messages",
                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
    }
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {

        statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `abcinc`.`employees`"
                + "WHERE (`EmployeeID`,`First_Name`,`Last_Name`,`Birthday`,`Dept_Name`)VALUES("
                + "'" + jTextField1.getText() + "'," 
                + "'" + jTextField2.getText() + "'," 
                + "'" + jTextField3.getText() + "'," 
                + "'" + jTextField4.getText() + "',"
                + "'" + jTextField5.getText() + "');");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful Update!!!", "Database Messages",
                      JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, error.getMessage(), "Database Messages",
                      JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
    }
}
```

Comment: You SQL syntax for ``DELETE`` is not correct (there's nothing like ``VALUES`` for delete).

Comment: Thanks everyone. This code was from my professor who created this. I was trying to follow it but did not understand. The fields are blank where a user can input information. The primary key is the SS(employee id) of the person being entered. I will try the below suggestions

Comment: Your professor needs to use prepared statements.

Comment: private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {

        statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `abcinc`.`employees`"
                + "WHERE employeeid=1")

So I am guessing it would/should look something like this?

Comment: AFAIK DELETE returns always successfull (when syntax correct) even when the WHERE clause matches no record.

Answer (score 2):

Delete does not follow that syntax.

try something like

```
DELETE FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn='X' AND myothercolumn='Y';
```

[see docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: thanks, i tried this but not working for some reason:

 statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `abcinc`.`employees`"
                    + "WHERE 'employeeID'= jTextField1.getText()");

Comment: probably your quoting of values. i suggest reading the error message you get and the documentation posted in my answer.

Comment: also, try without the `jtextfield` integration and just get a query working first. your quoting is wrong and it would be clear if you focused on one bit at a time.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE (`EmployeeID`,`First_Name`,`Last_Name`,`Birthday`,`Dept_Name`)VALUES

Needs to be a condition such as

WHERE EmployeeID=1

Secondly,

- "'" + jTextField1.getText() + "'," 
              + "'" + jTextField2.getText() + "'," 
              + "'" + jTextField3.getText() + "'," 
              + "'" + jTextField4.getText() + "',"
              + "'" + jTextField5.getText() +

is a very poor way of constructing the query as it leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks.

You should use a prepared statement with parameters and then insert the parameters.

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;

try {

ps = conection.prepareStatement("insert into mytable (ID) values (?)");

ps.setString(1, jTextField5.getText());

ps.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, for now i rather not change it to a preparedstatement as i not that familar with java yet. I rather keep it as how my "insert" works. I will try the where employeeID=1. Also when i use employeeid=1, where is the "1" from?

Answer (score 0):

i think the delete data sql syntax is like 'DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN = ?',it's not contain the 'values'

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL delete statement is incorrect.

I guess Employee number is unique in your table so you should try

> DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE EmployeeID='someid';

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but for some reason it is not taking it
 statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `abcinc`.`employees`"
                    + "WHERE 'employeeID'= jTextField1.getText()");

Comment: note that you are placing jTextField1.getText inside **" "** making it a string and not function call

Answer (score 0):

The VALUES-clause is only for use in insert-statements.

Inside a WHERE-clause you'll have to use single predicates like

```
WHERE EmployeeID = ...
  AND First_Name = ...
```

You don't have to specify al attributes of the row you want to delete but only those that are needed to identify the row(s).

Comment: Thanks, i tried that, but for some reason it is not taking it
 statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM `abcinc`.`employees`"
                    + "WHERE 'employeeID'= jTextField1.getText()");